# Adding newline character to printf() changes code behaviour

Tags: c, linux, printf

For some reason, adding `\n` to `printf()` changes the behaviour of below code. The code without `\n` prints `(null)` whereas the code with `\n` leads to `Segmentation fault`.

**Printf.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
}
```

**Printf.c - Output**

```
$ gcc -o Printf Printf.c
$ ./Printf
(null)
```

**Printf_Newline.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

**Printf_Newline.c - Output**

```
$ gcc -o Printf_Newline Printf_Newline.c
$ ./Printf_Newline
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am curious to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Please explain which compiler (*gcc* which version) did you use and under what OS, environment information is very relevant in this case.

Comment: Who knows what will happen when your code has a bug in it that causes undefined behaviour. Maybe next time you run it, the world will end - best to fix the bugs :)

Comment: You have to supply an argument when you run the program. Such as `$./Printf apples`

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi - `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: @ChrisTurner You think that it's indeed undefined behavior to pass a `NULL` pointer for a `"%s"` specifier, that's strictly true but why then did it print `(null)` in the other case if there is no such string passed to `printf()`? I think this might be an actual bug somewhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Yes, I'm aware of it :-)

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: "*why then did it print (null)*" because the GNU guys were creative, had free beers, too much time ... whatever.

Comment: @Beginner Ubuntu tends to be peculiar, sadly I don't like it precisely because of that. So I can't test if it happens, I am 99.9% sure it will not occur on my arch linux, but I will try to check.

Comment: @alk I know that. I was just trying to make the following point: we would expect it to print `(null)` in the second case too, because as you said the *GNU* guys were creative. And indeed, there is no way that `(null)` would be the behavior of the undefined behavior of the given case.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: I extended my comment ... the middle reason might be the case .. at least it would explain this behaviour better, who knows ;-) Defining UB "a bit" still leaves it being UB, right?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi why do you think that `argv[1]` would be NULL given that it's beyond the bounds of the array - it could have any value

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Strictly speaking, it depends on whether `argc` is at least 1.

Comment: @ChrisTurner argv[argc] is always a null pointer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Both are **undefined behavior**, so an answer could stop right here.

But there's at least an explanation for the output of `(null)`. This is an extension in `glibc` (the GNU C library). Passing `0` for `%s` in `printf()` is considered *undefined* in the C standard and therefore could very well result in a *crash*. The developers of `glibc` decided to do something meaningful instead.

The reason the second crashes nevertheless is that with the newline, the compiler decides to *optimize*: Instead of `printf("%s\n", argv[1])`, it executes `puts(argv[1])`, which is semantically equivalent according to the C standard, therefore an allowed optimization. But `glibc`s "(null)-trick" is only implemented in `printf()`.

There's another **undefined behavior** in your program: You potentially access `argv` **out of bounds**. There's no guarantee what value you will find at `argv[i]` when `i > argc`. There's a slight chance `argc` could be 0, so you could experience **anything else** as well.

Comment: Where did you get this `glibc` thing? o__O

Comment: It's undefined behaviour only if `i > argc` (strictly greater, not greater-or-equal) - `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be a null pointer.  But I don't see any check of `argc >= 1` in that program.

Comment: This is great, I wouldn't have thought of it but looking at the generated assembly confirms what you say is correct. In the case where the `"\n"` is present, the format string does not appear in the generated assembly at all.

Comment: "*decides to optimize*": Nice spot: `printf("%d, %s\n", argc, argv[1]);` doesn't crash for `argc` being equal to 1, but prints: `1, (null)<newline>` :-)

Comment: @alk and what if argc is 0? I don't think this is forbidden.

Comment: Ah well, yes, ok, fair enough. Do you know any implementation where `argc` is ever less then 1?

Comment: @alk Perhaps if you call `execvp` with `argv[0]` set to `NULL`.

Comment: @alk would have to test that, but maybe i can provoke it with `char *argv[] = { 0 }; execv("foo", argv);`

Comment: i am a little upset at gcc for doing this optimization on the (implicit) `-O0`, though.. this is the kind of thing it shouldn't do with optimizations disabled

Comment: @hanshenrik well, you *could* argue that this particular optimization would never influence observable behavior even for *undefined* cases if it wasn't for the extended glibc `printf()` ;)

Answer (score 11):

The code has **undefined behavior** in both cases if the program is not given any command line arguments, so anything can happen.

Since you are curious (good for you!), here is a potential explanation for what you observe:

- `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` can be optimized by the compiler into `puts(argv[1]);` whereas `printf("%s", argv[1]);` still invokes `printf()`.
- some implementations of `printf` accept a null pointer as an argument for the `%s` conversion, hence the output `(null)`.
- `puts()` has undefined behavior for a null pointer, in your case a segmentation fault.

Try compiling both without any optimization (`-O0`) and see if you get `(null)` output with and without the `\n`.

You can play with [godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/kamgJC) and see how `clang` changes behavior with -O0, but not `gcc`.

Comment: Yes, `--O0` flag didn't make any change to the behaviour.

Comment: @Beginner: it actually depends on your compiler, recent versions of `gcc` seem to optimize the `printf` even when told not to with `-O0`, whereas `clang` does keep the call to `printf()`.

Answer (score 2):

Executing with no arguments `argv[1]` shall be `NULL` pointer. With `argv[1]` being `NULL`

```
printf("%s", argv[1]);
```

will invoke undefined behavior.